# How to use VBA to generate an Excel table

Tags: excel, vba

I an new to VBA. How I can I use VBA to generate a table based on data from another table? For example: generate table2  from table1, where I would get all possible combinations for Color key;

table 1 consist of: color, model, year.

In table 2 I want to generate all possible combinations for color+model+year

[image: excel sheet screenshot]

I manage to write this code

```
Sub generatedinput() 
    Dim listA As Range
    Dim listB As Range
    Dim listC As Range

    Range("D11:F999").Clear

    Set listA = Range("I11", Range("I11").End(xlDown))
    Set listB = Range("J11", Range("J11").End(xlDown))
    Set listC = Range("K11", Range("K11").End(xlDown))

    y = 11

    For Each cellA In listA
        For Each cellB In listB
            For Each cellC In listC
                Cells(y, 4).Value = cellA.Value
                Cells(y, 5).Value = cellB.Value
                Cells(y, 6).Value = cellC.Value
                y = y + 1
            Next
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

But generates for empties cells as well. How to skip blank cells?

Answer (score 0):

It's kind of ugly, but it gets the job done.  Your code is close, you just have to check for empty cells.

```
Public Sub MakeComboTable()

    Dim rColor As Range
    Dim rModel As Range
    Dim rYear As Range
    Dim lCnt As Long

    For Each rColor In Sheet1.Range("G4:G11").Cells
        If Not IsEmpty(rColor.Value) Then
            For Each rModel In Sheet1.Range("H4:H11").Cells
                If Not IsEmpty(rModel.Value) Then
                    For Each rYear In Sheet1.Range("I4:I11").Cells
                        If Not IsEmpty(rYear.Value) Then
                            lCnt = lCnt + 1
                            Sheet1.Range("B1").Offset(lCnt, 0).Value = rColor.Value
                            Sheet1.Range("B1").Offset(lCnt, 1).Value = rModel.Value
                            Sheet1.Range("B1").Offset(lCnt, 2).Value = rYear.Value
                        End If
                    Next rYear
                End If
            Next rModel
        End If
    Next rColor

End Sub
```

Comment: thanks. I additionally  want to clear  table 2 before running the scrip.  There for I tried to include `Range .Clear` command. Is that right  ?

Comment: Also how to achieve if don't know the range length for `rcolor`. I want code to scroll down for   `rcolor` until it finds last entry.  ( Color column will contain no gaps)

Comment: I use `Range.ClearContents`.

Comment: It kind of depends on your situation. Take a look at `Range.CurrentRegion` and `Range.End`